# How to get Context.User.HasClaim() and [Authorize("Administrator", "Allow")] to function when using windows Kerberos authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

- Given: **Identity Framework 7 Beta 3** & **Entity Framework 7**  (***vNext***)
- Given: Windows Kerberos authentication.

---

Context.User has the IPrincipal assigned from the windows Kerberos authentication consequently Context.User object does not contain the claims assigned to the matching Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityUser that are stored using Entity Framework.

Thus:

- Context.User.HasClaim() can not determine authorizations
- [Authorize("Administrator", "Allow")] attribute on a controller action method to determine authorization at the controller can not function.

What can I do to get Context.User.HasClaim() and [Authorize("Administrator", "Allow")] to function correctly when using windows Kerberos authentication?

Comment: Identity Framework 7 Beta 3? I smell a typo.